# regular expression syntax or someother error

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
/\w{0,5}[хx]([хx\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[уy]([уy\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[ёiлeеюийя]\w{0,7}|\w{0,6}[пp]([пp\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[iие]([iие\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[3зс]([3зс\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[дd]\w{0,10}|[сcs][уy]([уy\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[4чkк]\w{1,3}|\w{0,4}[bб]([bб\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[lл]([lл\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[yя]\w{0,10}|\w{0,8}[её][bб][лске@eыиаa][наи@йвл]\w{0,8}|\w{0,4}[еe]([еe\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[бb]([бb\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[uу]([uу\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[н4ч]\w{0,4}|\w{0,4}[еeё]([еeё\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[бb]([бb\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[нn]([нn\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[уy]\w{0,4}|\w{0,4}[еe]([еe\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[бb]([бb\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[оoаa@]([оoаa@\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[тnнt]\w{0,4}|\w{0,10}[ё]([ё\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[б]\w{0,6}|\w{0,4}[pп]([pп\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[иeеi]([иeеi\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[дd]([дd\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[oоаa@еeиi]([oоаa@еeиi\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[рr]\w{0,12}/i
```

when I am trying to check it with a script I get the following error:

Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier ']' in C:\xampp\htdocs\guestbook\index.php on line 70

is that because of []? Or I have to search the problem in my code? the idea is that I am pooling the expression from the database and replacing the message with them. Here is the code.

```
$expq = "SELECT `Expression` FROM `expressions` LIMIT 0, 30 ";
     $expr=  mysqli_query($db, $expq);
     $exp=  mysqli_fetch_array($expr);
     foreach ($exp as $expression)
     {
         echo $expression;
     $replacement = "";

$message = preg_replace($expression, $replacement, $message);


     }
     if ($message=="")
     {
         echo 'Текст сообщения не заполнен или содержит не цензурную лексику';
     }
 else { //insert the message into database
```

Comment: Try replacing \ to \\

Comment: Will fix that. Now problem isn't their but thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message

```
Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier ']'
```

states, that there is a modifier ]. A modifier is always at the end of a regex. Since at your regexes real end is an /i, this cannot be true. So somewhere in your regex is an occurence of /], which is treated as the end of your regex.
So in my eyes, you have 2 ways to fix that. Either you follow Justinas advice and add double \ to your regex, or you set the delimiters to a symbol, which does not occur in your regex. I usually use the "~". Your regex would look like this in the end:

```
~\w{0,5}[хx]([хx\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[уy]([уy\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[ёiлeеюийя]\w{0,7}|\w{0,6}[пp]([пp\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[iие]([iие\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[3зс]([3зс\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[дd]\w{0,10}|[сcs][уy]([уy\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[4чkк]\w{1,3}|\w{0,4}[bб]([bб\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[lл]([lл\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[yя]\w{0,10}|\w{0,8}[её][bб][лске@eыиаa][наи@йвл]\w{0,8}|\w{0,4}[еe]([еe\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[бb]([бb\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[uу]([uу\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[н4ч]\w{0,4}|\w{0,4}[еeё]([еeё\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[бb]([бb\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[нn]([нn\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[уy]\w{0,4}|\w{0,4}[еe]([еe\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[бb]([бb\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[оoаa@]([оoаa@\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[тnнt]\w{0,4}|\w{0,10}[ё]([ё\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[б]\w{0,6}|\w{0,4}[pп]([pп\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[иeеi]([иeеi\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[дd]([дd\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[oоаa@еeиi]([oоаa@еeиi\s\!@#\$%\^&*+-\|\/]{0,6})[рr]\w{0,12}~i
```